# Insert resource into submit value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, localization, interpolation

I want to localize Submit button in ASP.NET MVC application but don't know how to inerpolate it into value attribute.

```
<input type="submit" value="Resources.Global.Create" />
```

It prints Resources.Global.Create on form, but it should print localized value not variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the magic Razor character (`@`):

```
<input type="submit" value="@Resources.Global.Create" />
```